# Android get Sharedpreferences in SQLite database file

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, android-context

please i have this sharedpreference class in my DBTool.java class and it is giving me this error The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (DBTools)" . In the getAllcontact() method.......

this is the DBTools.java class

package com.mall.our;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import com.mall.first.MainActivity;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.ContextWrapper;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

    public class DBTools extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        public DBTools(Context applicationContext){

            super(applicationContext, "contactbook.db", null, 1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

            String query = "CREATE TABLE contacts ( contactId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fromm TEXT, too TEXT ," +
                    "state TEXT, message TEXT, time TEXT, latest TEXT, rig TEXT, picc TEXT)";

            database.execSQL(query);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts";

            database.execSQL(query);
            onCreate(database);

        }

        public void insertContact(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("fromm", queryValues.get("fromm"));
            values.put("too", queryValues.get("too"));


            database.insert("contacts", null, values);

            database.close();

        }

        public int updateContact(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("fromm", queryValues.get("fromm"));
            values.put("too", queryValues.get("too"));

            return database.update("contacts", values, 
                    "contactId" + " = ?", new String[] {queryValues.get("contactId") });

        }

        public void deleteContact(String id){

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

            String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contactId='" + id + "'";

            database.execSQL(deleteQuery);

        }

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllContacts(){

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(DBTools.this);
            String friend = sp.getString("user", "anon");

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE too='" + friend + "'";


            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                do{

                    HashMap<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    contactMap.put("contactId", cursor.getString(0));
                    contactMap.put("fromm", cursor.getString(1));
                    contactMap.put("too", cursor.getString(2));


                    contactArrayList.add(contactMap);

                } while(cursor.moveToNext());

            }

            return contactArrayList;

        }

        public HashMap<String, String> getContactInfo(String id){

            HashMap<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactId='" + id + "'";

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                do{

                    contactMap.put("contactId", cursor.getString(0));
                    contactMap.put("fromm", cursor.getString(1));
                    contactMap.put("too", cursor.getString(2));


                } while(cursor.moveToNext());

            }

            return contactMap;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the right `Context`. The `SQLiteOpenHelper` class is not derived from `Context`, and thus cannot act as a valid `Context`.

In your `DBTools` class, create a variable

```
private Context appContext;
```

and initialize it in the constructor:

```
public DBTools(Context applicationContext){

    super(applicationContext, "contactbook.db", null, 1);
    this.appContext = applicationContext;

}
```

Now, replace

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(DBTools.this);
```

with

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

> getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is
>   not applicable for the arguments (DBTools)

Because  `getDefaultSharedPreferences` takes Context object as parameters instead of `DBTools.this` or any other class context.

To fix this issue create a private Context object as assign value in object inside `DBTools` class constructor in which you are passing context when creating object of `DBTools` class:

```
   private Context mContext;
   public DBTools(Context applicationContext){
        super(applicationContext, "contactbook.db", null, 1);
        this.mContext=applicationContext;
    }
```

Now, use `mContext` as parameter to `getDefaultSharedPreferences` method:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your method a `Context` object or have it reference a context object in your class.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllContacts(Context context) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

You can also use `getApplicationContext()` to get the context, however the above method is safer.

You can safely get the context from an Activity you're calling your method from with `yourActivity.getContext()`